# Airflow sends metrics by statsd but not all of them

Tags: airflow, statsd

Recently I have updated my airflow.cfg to enable metrics thought Statsd.

I have injected this settings to airflow.cfg:

I'm injecting this configuration:

```
AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__STATSD_ON=True
AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__STATSD_HOST=HOSTNAME
AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__STATSD_PORT=9125
AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__STATSD_PREFIX=airflow
```

I'm not using standard Statsd service, but [Statsd-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_exporter) which use Statsd protocol, so from my knowledge I can point directly Airflow to send metrics to Stats-exporter. By default it works on 9125 port.

After Statsd-exporter receives metrics, Prometheus is able to scrape them in regular manner.

All fine, all good. Moreover I made my mapping file to Statsd-exporter where I use a bit regex but.... my issue is that when I open WEB UI of Statsd-exported (9102 port) I see part of Airflow metrics, but not all of them!.

Documentation says about list of metrics [here](https://airflow.apache.org/metrics.html)

For instance I see that Airflow sends: ti_failures, ti_successes, dagbag_size etc. But there are completely no metrics like: dag...duration or executor.open_slots and couple others.

Really big thank you for anyone who ever played with Statsd and Airflow, as I have no clue:(

Answer (score 1):

I recently instrumented airflow and its metrics to be exported from statsd to prometheus.
In my architecture I have airflow running in Kubernetes pods and these specifically are:

- scheduler
- worker
- flower
- web

Only `scheduler`, `worker` and `web` have a side-car container to export statsd metrics (let's call these `metrics pods`).

And the list of metrics you see in official docs (https://airflow.apache.org/metrics.html) are not available to all metric pods.

To adhere to your specific problem, `dag...duration` are exported by worker node.

Comment: I have edited worker node's configuration file and set statsd_on=True. Still, I'm not getting any metrics of scheduler or airflow on 9102 port.  I have used this command for running the statsd exporter. **docker run -d -p 9102:9102 -p 9125:9125 -v /tmp/statsd_mapping.yml:/tmp/statsd_mapping.yml prom/statsd-exporter --statsd.mapping-config=/tmp/statsd_mapping.yml**